# Firefox displaying identical CSS differently as opposed to Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am new to web design and I have encountered a discrepancy between Firefox and Chrome in displaying elements.

I have created two divs that are intended to be "blocks" to make up a "+". On Chrome, they are aligned as expected but on Firefox they are severely misaligned.

Here's my code:

```
<li id="juniorLinkList">
 <a id="juniorLink" href="#">Junior</a>
 <div id="horizPlusjun"></div>
 <div id="vertPlusjun"></div>
</li>
```

I made the CSS of the two elements the exact same for debugging purposes and I expected to see the elements overlap, however, they remained misaligned.

```
#horizPlusjun {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "";
    margin-top: 12.2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#vertPlusjun {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    content: "";
    margin-top: 12.2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2.5px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Here is the result of this code:

[Misaligned elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0e3I.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uffg7.png)

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can remove `display: inline-block`; when you use absolute positioning, the divs are no longer treated as "inline", so they'll automatically be `block`.

Comment: Please post [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can't you just use a literal "+" character and apply font styling?

Comment: @TimRoberts - that's not correct. Removing `display:inline-block' will change the div's positions in the OP's case. While `position:absolute` will cause their computed display value to become `block`, they will retain their static position, which is different for `inline-block` than for `block`.